# Is it possible sign a plain text string with RSA private key on Google App Engine with Java SDK?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rsa

Is it possible sign a plain text string with RSA private key on Google App Engine with Java SDK?

Thanks

Comment: Sure. Convert the string to byte[] then use java.security.Signature to sign it. Possibly, there is some point where you are stuck, but unfortunately, you didn't tell us exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

These two links should have all you need to encrypt and decrypt using RSA.

[RSA Encryption in Java 1](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml)

[RSA Encryption in Java 2](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption_2.shtml)

Comment: Pointing to RSA encryption is kind of misleading. The OP looks for signatures.